# Jenkins: Access global passwords in powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, passwords, global

I am having trouble accessing the jenkins global password as an environment variable in powershell. I have done the following. Not sure what else I am missing.

1. Installed Credentials Binding Plugin, Environment Injector Plugin, Mask Passwords Plugin, Hudson PowerShell plugin
2. Created a global password entry within manage credentials as gluser
3. In my build, I have a powershell call with the build environment defined for inject passwords to the build as environment variables and checked for global passwords.
4. None of the following get me to reference the global password in my powershell scripts
   `$env:gluser`
   `$gluser`

None of them seem to let me access the global password within powershell call from Jenkins. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 42):

Don't confuse [**EnvInject plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) and [**Credentials Binding plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin). The two do quite different things, however **both** allow the manage passwords globally, yet differently.

### EnvInject way

- **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System**
- Under **Global Password**

  1. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>.
  2. Enter name (of environment variable) and password.
- **Job** -> **Configure**
- Under **Build Environment**

  3. check *Inject passwords to the build as environment variables*.
  4. Check *Global passwords*.
  5. Check *Mask password parameters*.

### Credentials Binding way

- **Manage Jenkins** -> **Manage Credentials**

  1. Click <kbd>Add Credentials</kbd> (without domain).
  2. Select **Username with password** OR **Secret text**.
  3. Enter *Username* and *Password* OR *Secret*.
- **Job** -> **Configure**
- Under **Build Environment**

  1. Check **Use secret text(s) or file(s)**.
  2. Under **Bindings**, click <kbd>Add</kbd>.
  3. Select **Username and password** OR **Secret text**.
  4. Enter **Variable** name that you want to hold your credentials value.
  5. Select **Specific credentials** radio button.
  6. Select your configured credentials from the drop-down

### In your Powershell

- Access these as you would any other environment variable:
  `$env:VAR_NAME`
  where `VAR_NAME` is the environment variable name (i.e. step 2 from EnvInject way, or step 4 from Credentials Binding way)

### Appendix

**EnvInject vs Credentials Binding**

- EnvInject passwords will show encrypted in list of environment variables.
- EnvInject passwords will show starred (*****) in console output.
- EnvInject passwords use the same variable name as the global configuration, so you have to remember that global variable name.
  |
- CB passwords are shown plain text in list of environment variables.
- CB passwords are not starred in console output.
- CB passwords can be bound to any variable name you want in the job from a dropdown, so you don't have to remember that global variable name.
  |
- Credentials Binding is really more for biding credential files, like certificates and keys, rather than password values.

**Username with Password vs Secret Text.**

- The former is available in the form `username:password`.
- The latter is just `secret`.

Answer (score 0):

In our build we use it the following way (actual code):

```
$deploymentdir = $env:VC_RES + "\azure"
. ".\src\Extensions\Setup\VirtoCommerce.PowerShell\deploy-tfs.ps1" -deployment $deploymentdir -solutiondir $env:WORKSPACE
```

and then pass $deploymentdir as a parameter to ps1, works fine.

The environment variable VC_RES is configured under "Manage Jenkins"->Global Properties. There is a checkbox next to "Environment Variables" and we set those in there. The WORKSPACE variable is set by jenkins itself.