# Passing Jenkins user credential to remote script as a parameter securely

Tags: security, jenkins, ldap

My corp Jenkins instance uses the corp LDAP for user authentication. We have a requirement to automate one on the internal portals which also takes corp LDAP for authentication.

Since there is a restriction of using "dummy" LDAP for automation purpose, i am thinking of passing my (or Jenkins users) corp credential to automation script securely.

1. How do I pass the Jenkins logged in user credential as  parameters to a job.
2. How do I **securely** pass the  parameters to job that executes remote script.I dont want to store / pass corp LDAP anywhere between Jenkins and remote.

Advanced thanks. appreciate inputs and any suggestions on alternate solution to meets this requirement.

Comment: Explained in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152656/jenkins-access-global-passwords-in-powershell/27158053#27158053

Comment: Salv , thanks for the link. I think we are pretty close but I want more. I dont want to enter my username/password in jenkins configuration system. It should automatically pick based on the logged in user credential. I doubt its possible. Also is it possible to pass the base64 encoded username:password to build so that i can directly use the encoded text in http auth header for automation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question I stumbled on while searching answers for a similar issue. But I believe you can use the apitoken in place for the password. To find out apitoken, go to http(s)://yourJenkinsURL/user/yourID/configure, you will find it there.