# Jenkins svn export build step

Tags: authentication, svn, jenkins

On my Jenkins server, I have a project that checks some source code out of SVN and runs a build script called MakeInstaller.ps1 that got checked out along with the source code.  It's pretty straight-forward and this part is working great.

What's not working great is that part of MakeInstaller.ps1 attempts to do an svn export of a specific revision of some other source code, but it doesn't have the credentials to connect to SVN.  When I run the build-scripts on my PC this is totally fine, because Tortoise SVN has the credentials cached.

Jenkins has my SVN credentials already, but that's only used when Jenkins checks out the source code, not when my build script attempts to check out the source code.

I've tried:

1. Installing the Tortoise SVN command-line tools on the machine that's running Jenkins.  This fixed my initial "svn.exe not found" error, but it has no way of knowing my credentials for this server
2. I even logged into the SVN server using Tortoise SVN on that machine to attempt it to get it to cache the credentials, but it's still not working.  I'm guessing it's because the Jenkins service does not run under the same user that I was logged in as.

I feel like I'm getting off on the wrong path though.  It seems a bit odd to have Tortoise SVN installed on that machine along side whatever SVN client the Jenkins SVN plug-in is already using.

**My question:**  Is there a way to do SVN export from inside a build-script in Jenkins and have it use the credentials that Jenkins already knows about?  Can I use the same svn.exe that the Jenkins SVN plug-in is using?  I really don't want to include the credentials in the build script itself.

Most of the similar questions I found involved the initial check-out failing due to bad credentials, not a check-out that happens as part of the build script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I ended up doing something like [Jenkins: Access global passwords in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152656/jenkins-access-global-passwords-in-powershell)

I had to use EnvInject because the Credentials Binding plugin was giving me an error when I tried to save the project.  This involved adding another instance of my SVN password to Jenkins, and hardcoding the Jenkins user name into my build script, but it's working.

Now the build script attempts to authenticate with a dummy svn info command.  If I'm running the script on my local machine, that works and it proceeds without a user-name or password.  If the dummy svn info command fails, it attempts to log in with --username Jenkins and --password $env:svnpassword where the svnpassword environment variable is provided by EnvInject.