# Reference global credentials in Bash script in Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I created global credentials (username,password) and gave a custom ID. How do I reference this ID in my Bash script? I checked "inject global password" in my job configuration already.

I tried [Jenkins: Access global passwords in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152656/jenkins-access-global-passwords-in-powershell) but doesn't work.

Assume the ID of the global credentials is "USER_PASSWORD", my bash script tried:

```
echo ${USER_PASSWORD}
echo ${env:USER_PASSWORD}
```

Doesn't work. I read some online post I would need to query Jenkins API to get the credentials. That doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 62):

Using the [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin), global credentials may be injected into the build context. This is done by checking the checkbox labeled *Use secret text(s) or file(s)* in the **Build Environment** section of the job's configuration page. Add a *Username and password (separated)* binding, choose the specific credential you created, and define your username and password variables.

Here's an example of the Credentials Binding Plugin in use, but with a colon-delimited username/password variable instead of the two separate variables:

[image: Credentials Binding Plugin example]

You can then use the username and/or password variables you defined in your shell script. Assuming a username value of `foo` and a password value of `bar`...

*Username and password* binding, variable name `USER_CREDENTIALS`:

```
echo $USER_CREDENTIALS # -> foo:bar
```

*Username and password (separated)* binding, variable names `USER_ID` and `USER_PASSWORD`:

```
echo $USER_ID          # -> foo
echo $USER_PASSWORD    # -> bar
```

Comment: You can even get the credential to inject as a job parameter by choosing **Parameter expression**. This is nice :)

Comment: This does not answer the question of parameterizing access to a number of credentials.  Danny Hajicek's answer does.

Answer (score 43):

If your credentials ID is "USER_PASSWORD", you have to read it using eg. the following command: `USER_CREDENTIALS = credentials('USER_PASSWORD')`. After doing this, the username and password are available in the following environment variables: `USER_CREDENTIALS_USR` and `USER_CREDENTIALS_PSW`. Jenkins always adds `_USR` and `_PSW` endings to the names of the variables.

Example pipeline (I did not fully test it, but should work):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        USER_CREDENTIALS = credentials('USER_PASSWORD')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Run') {
            steps {
                sh "echo $USER_CREDENTIALS_USR"
                sh "echo $USER_CREDENTIALS_PSW"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you get `****` (four asterisks) as output, it's ok - Jenkins automatically masks usernames and passwords in the console output.

More information: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#usernames-and-passwords .

Answer (score 40):

I couldn't find a straight forward answer for how to use the parameterized Credentials Parameter username and password as environmental variables in a bash script. The following worked for me:

1. Add a Credentials Parameter. I called it "CREDENTIALS". Credential type "Username and password."
   [image: Credentials Parameter Screenshot]
2. In the Build Environment check "Use secret text(s) or files(s)".
3. Add a "Username and password (separated)" binding. I set my Username Variable to USER and Password Variable to PW. For Credentials select "Parameter expression" and put in the name from step one. In this case it would be ${CREDENTIALS}.
   [image: Credentials Binding Screenshot]
4. Now `${USER}` and `${PW}` are available to the bash script.

Comment: I tried it but the `echo` command in the bash script with the user doesn't print the required value...

Answer (score 5):

In my case i resolved with withCredentials [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/).

```
stage('Commit') {
   withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'hash', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
      sh 'svn commit xxx.ear -m "Comment" --username $USERNAME --password $PASSWORD'
   }
}
```

Comment: He mentions he wants the credentials in a bash script though, not in a pipeline

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have used below code to read the credentials configured in Active

```
Choices Paramater Plugin's Groovy Script to populate the choices.

        def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
            com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials.class,
            jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
        )
    
    def user = creds[0].username
    def pwd= creds[0].password
    def gettags = ("git ls-remote --tags https://$user:$pwd@github.com/<yourRepo>.git").execute()
```

This way the credentials are not hardcoded in the script, which makes it manageable if we want to change the generated token
Note: We were using GitHubTokens to perform the operations instead of password

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was solely that curly brackets did not work.

```
#!/bin/bash

# did not work:
echo ${USERNAME}

# DID work:
echo $USERNAME
```